# Bug in .NET Sockets?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, wireshark

I've been breaking my head over this bug in my program that would rarely occur and now I finally got it down to something that is not related to my code, or at least that is what I think.

```
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[512];
IPEndPoint f = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(packet.ipAddres), SNMP_PORT);
socket.SendTo(packet.GetBytes(), f);
IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(packet.ipAddres), 0);
EndPoint senderRemote = (EndPoint)sender;
socket.ReceiveFrom(dataBuffer, ref senderRemote);
```

Wireshark packet dump and Visual Studio dump of the variable 'dataBuffer' do not match, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bODg0.png)

Wireshark is giving me the expected response. Visual Studio, or my code, does not.
So how is this possible? Am I using the .NET socket object incorrectly?

Comment: Please improve your question. Copypaste the code into the question. Of course there isn't a bug in the .NET framework at this level, otherwise everybody would have trouble with it. Show what you expect to happen and what really happens. [`Socket.ReceiveFrom()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdfskwcy.aspx) will return an int indicating how many bytes are received. Do you receive all data you expect? Show some more debugging info please. :)

Comment: Well after looking for a bug for such a long time you start to question everything. I didn't expect the .NET framework to contain such bugs. And yes I've checked all these things, everything worked as intented except the data would be different from what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, the remote SNMP software on the switch.
When I send 1 GetNextRequestPDU to the switch, it should send you 1 response packet.
But sometimes this specific switch would send me 10 times the same response packet.
This results in the socket having to process 10 times the same packet before it would actually see the 'correct' packet. This wasn't visible in the wireshark dump as the duplicated response happened BEFORE the visible packet in wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the same.
The first selected byte in wireshark corresponds to index [27] in Visual Studio. It would be more obvious if you switch Visual Studio to display numbers in hexadecimal format.

Comment: It is not, very similar but there are a few bytes that are different. But thanks for the tip, I was wondering already if I could switch visual studio to hex output.